# update não funciona depois de requisição ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

boa noite pessoal estou criando um sistema e nele faço um requisição dinamica com ajax para buscar nomes dos clientes eu tenho uma link que abre um modal com as informações para dar update ,as quando clico botão submit da refresh a pagina

```
function exibirConteudo(id) {

            $('#myModal').modal('show');    

    // Verificando Browser
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// Arquivo PHP juntamento com a id da noticia (método GET)
var url = "liks.php?recordID="+id;

    req.open("GET", url, true);

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // Exibe a mensagem "Aguarde..." enquanto carrega
    if(req.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('conteudoModal').innerHTML = 'Aguarde...';
    }

        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

    // Resposta retornada pelo exibir.php
    var resposta = req.responseText;

    // Abaixo colocamos a resposta na div conteudo
    document.getElementById('conteudoModal').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
}
req.send(null);


}
```

este é meu botão salvar que abre no modal

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_cli"  value="<?php echo $row['id_cli']; ?>" />
           <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit">
        Salvar
       </button>
    </form>
```

e esta é a minha requisição ajax para o botão salvar

```
$("#form_cli").submit(function(e) {
    var url2 = "con_cliente.php" 
    var url = "update/update_cli.php"; 
     if (confirm('Tem certeza que quer cadastrar o cliente?')){ 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#form_cli").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
    {

        $("#alterafade").fadeOut(800, function(){
                            $("#alterafade").load(url2).fadeIn().delay(2000);
               });

               //utilizar o dado retornado para alterar algum dado da tela.
           }

         });
     }

    e.preventDefault();// esse comando serve para previnir que o form realmente realize o submit e atualize a tela.
});
```

é assim que é meu modal
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quano eu clico em salvar ele da refresh e o endereço da pagina fica da quele jeito

Answer (score 0):

Analisando o seu código você esta utilizando o método `GET` para buscar nomes dos clientes, e esta utilizando o método `post` **para fazer o update**.
   O método correto para se fazer um **update é o `PUT`** que Requisita que um recurso seja "guardado" na URI fornecida. Se o recurso já existir, ele deve ser atualizado. Se não existir, pode ser criado.
   Se você utilizar o `POST` O método tenta criar um novo registro e não altera-lo.